# Xamarin Forms: Font icon not getting rendered at run-time

Tags: android, ios, fonts, xamarin.forms

I'm using a font to display icons in my mobile app. The problem is, font icon is displayed correctly when I write it directly into xaml file but it doesn't work when I set it at runtime.

I have implemented the font icon by creating a Custom Label control and a Custom Renderer for each platform. I'm facing this problem on Android, haven't yet checked on iOS.

**Custom Label:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace fonticon
{
    public class IconLabel:Label
    {
        public IconLabel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom renderer for Android:**

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

// This informs the compiler that we're using this class to render an IconLabel on this platform
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(fonticon.IconLabel), typeof(fonticon.Droid.IconLabelRenderer))]
namespace fonticon.Droid
{
    public class IconLabelRenderer:LabelRenderer
    {
        // sets the font for the platform-specific ui component to be our custom font
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            // Note we're using the filename here, NOT the font family name
            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, "flatuiicons.ttf");
            Control.Typeface = font;
        }
    }
}
```

**Following XAML works:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:fonticon" 
    x:Class="fonticon.fonticonPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="mainContainer">
        <local:IconLabel x:Name="lblTestIcon" Text="&#xe012;" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="40" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Following code doesn't work:**

```
lblTestIcon.Text = "&#xe012;";
```

**Source of the implementation is following:**

https://blog.bitbull.com/2017/05/10/using-a-custom-icon-font-in-xamarin-forms/comment-page-1/#comment-1209

Comment: Have you covered step 5 from the article you posted? I've missed this step a few times and it just results in it being unable to find the font-pack....

Step 5. Import Your Custom Font Into Your Android Project
Right-click on the Assets directory in your Android project and select ‘Add Files’. Navigate to the font file you have chosen on your hard drive and add it to the project. Once the file has been added right-click on it and check the ‘Build Action’ is set to ‘AndroidAsset’.

Comment: The issue is fixed using following code which was told in the article but somehow I missed it.

Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode ("&#xe012;");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed using following code which was told in the article but somehow I missed it.

```
Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode ("&#xe012;");
```

Also, added following code to the Android Custom Renderer:

```
// sets the font for the platform-specific ui component to be our custom font
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    // Note we're using the filename here, NOT the font family name
    var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, "flatuiicons.ttf");
    Control.Typeface = font;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog on using font images](https://sturla.io/font-images-in-xamarin-forms/) you might find interesting and more modern than this approach.