# Xamarin.Forms font awesone using Label

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I am using Xamarin.Forms and having difficulty using FontAwesome.

This font has its specific code to use.

public const string InfoCircle = "\uf05a";

I need to use them in a listview menu.

If I use them directly by typing it in Label, it works fine, but if I bring the font value from an API for example, instead of the FontAwesome-converted icon, the font-specific code appears. How to make the font appear correctly?

Thanks.

[Print of iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDqur.png)

Comment: You can put constant label in datatemplate item of listview  and do not retreive icon as part of a data. I recommend to separate ui in design time and pure  data at runtime.

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945419/xamarin-forms-font-icon-not-getting-rendered-at-run-time

Comment: It should work. I followed [this article](https://www.wintellect.com/using-fontawesome5-xamarin-forms/) and it works on my side. Did you set the right FontFamily? How do you assign the value to label? Use data binding? Can you share your code or a simple test project?

Comment: Yes, fontfamily was informed. The solution found was to save the font characters as unescape in a field of type nvarchar. To convert to unescape I used this site https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html